# DISTINCT ON multiple columns, Order matters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How is it possible that the order of columns matter in a distinct. I get a different number of rows for

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_geom,plz) the_geom`

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (plz,the_geom) the_geom
```

Any ideas where I am thinking wrong? I am using postgreSQL 9.1.5.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: DISTINCT and DISTINCT ON are different things, check the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation suggests](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) that `DISTINCT ON` requires an `order by` starting with the same columns.  So this would work:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (the_geom,plz) 
        the_geom
,       plz
FROM    YourTable
ORDER BY 
        the_geom
,       plz
```

Omitting the correct `order by` could produce unexpected results.

Comment: That was it. I thought, it was unpredictable which row is selected (doesn't matter for me) but apparently the function is useless without the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2):

you're mixing up `DISTINCT` and `DISTINCT ON`, see [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might might want something a lot simpler.  Does this give you what you want?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT the_geom FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: I actually need them to be DISTINCT on only two columns and not everywhere. Your example should do that.